# How to resolve the conflict in key word and table column name when writing postgres sql sentence

Tags: plpgsql, keyword, conflict

I have tried the follow methods
like add ``, [], ""
all these methods can not work, and can find a way to resolve the problem.

And the codes as below(the conflict of the key word is "cursor"):

```
DO $$
BEGIN    
for tm in (select * from table_mine) loop
    tm.cursor=8855;
end loop;
END;
$$;
```

**the error is :**

syntax error at or near "."

LINE 5:    tm.cursor=8855;

```
        ^
```

Comment: Can you post any errors that you are getting?

Comment: I have updated the code, please

Comment: Resolved, the right oode is :  tm."CURSOR"

Answer (score 1):

This is plpgsql and not sql code, right? Pls. tag your question `plpgsql`. Actually the brackets are redundant.

```sql
for tm in select * from table_mine loop
    tm."cursor" = 8855;
    ...
end loop;
```

Names are enclosed in double quotes in Postgresql.

Comment: It's correct to use the brackets. the right code is : tm."CURSOR". Thanks a lot